# Spark Java QueryMap Use

Tags: spark-java

Hey guys could someone give me a hint in using the QueryMap in Spark. Im trying to realize a litte Spark API with a possibility to filtering and sorting entities.
Everything is working as expected but i cant figure it out how to built up the url query.

My query

> /matches?filter[name=guenther][firstName=max]

My Code

```
 public static QueryParamsMap getFilters(Request req){
    QueryParamsMap queryMap = req.queryMap("filter");
    return queryMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a litte research i found the extended Spark documentation.
http://javadoc.io/doc/com.sparkjava/spark-core/2.7.2
For these which still struggle, the URL is

> /matches?filter[name]=guenther&filter[firstName]=max